# How can I remove the last comma from a map?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have,

```
{
  mydata.map(({
    name
  }) => ( <p style = {{
        display: "inline" }} > { " " } { name }, </p>))
}
```

How can I remove the last comma in `banana, apple, orange,` the result of the code, that is, the one after `orange` and make it look something like this: `banana, apple, orange`?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Maybe using the index from the map callback `index === mydata.length - 1 ? '' : ','`?

Comment: Maybe better to use `Array.join(', ');`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
{mydata.map(({name}, idex) => (
                            <p style={{display:"inline"}}>
                                {" "}{name} {index === mydata.length - 1 ? "" : ","}
                            </p>
                            ))}
```

Answer (score 3):

Why are you using multiple p tags? I think, below code should do what you want to do.

```
     <p style={{display:"inline"}}>
         {mydata.map(item => item.name).join(', ')}
     </p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
{
 mydata.map(({name}, i) => (
          <p style={{display:"inline"}}>
            {i + 1 !== mydata.length? `{name}, ` : name} 
          </p>
     )
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As a matter of fact, you can do that with simple CSS:

`{mydata.map(({name}) => (<span className='item'>{" "}{name}</span>))}`

CSS:

`.item:not(:last-child)::after { content: ',' }`